# <sup>®</sup> ADA - VOICE OVER TEST IN iPHONE NOT WORKING

Tags: html, ios

IN ADA(Americans with Disabilities Act) TEST (ie) VoiceOver in iPhone not reading (Registered sign) <sup>®</sup> in HTML. 
NOTE: It is reading when it is put inside anchor tag with href link.

How to implement it in a span tag. 
Eg: `<span> HI <sup>®</sup> </span>`
  ReaD AS: HI Registered sign

Comment: Add a title attribute maybe?

Comment: I can't get you. could you please give me a example.

Comment: `<foo title="Let’s hope it will read this at least">®</foo>`

Comment: I should use <sup> and achieve this. Is there any other way

Comment: Then replace `foo` (which is an example name used as a placeholder only) with `sup` …

Comment: I am achieving it by using above idea.